# S-polynomial remainder of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials

In Page 90 of Ideal, Varieties and Algorithms, it shows a calculation of two polynomials being $x^3-2xy$ and $-2xy$, and shows the remainder being zero when using the S-polynomial method, but whenever I do the calculations my self I get $-4xy^2$ instead of zero, so is there anything I am missing.

Much appreciated if you can help thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

In that example, $f_1=x^3-2xy$, $f_2=-2xy$. The $S$-polynomial is computed this way:

$$S(f_1,f_2)=-2y(x^3-2xy)-x^2(-2xy)=4xy^2$$

Now $F=(f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4)$, where $f_3=-x^2, f_4=-2xy$. We need to divide $4xy^2$ by $F$. It can be seen easily that $4xy^2$ is not divisible by the first three polynomials, but can be divided by $f_4$ with remainder $0$.